How add spinner when load wire:navigate with selected route
Hi I want that when I click on the button bellow then show spinner until page swich. see this code bellow.
<a href="{{ route('order_lists') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
   wire:loading.attr="disabled" 
   wire:loading.class="d-inline-block" 
   wire:target="navigateToOrderLists" 
   wire:navigate
>
    <div wire:loading 
         wire:target="navigateToOrderLists" 
         class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" 
         role="status"
    >
    </div> 
    
    Order Lists
</a>

Please ask me if you confused.

Here some temporary solutions, waiting for a better implementation

I try it, but not working
